# Visual Studio 2008 Web application strange behaviour - Work only when debugging, Did not work when deployed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-applications

I created a .NET 3.5 Web application using Visual Studio 2008. (It is basically a text field, a button and a label field. When the button is pressed, the label field will display the text field content)

When I start debugging, everything work fine. However, when I deploy it on IIS 6, the button did not work at all.

I have give the folder (which I created using IIS Virtual Directory) IUSR account access (Read, 'List Folder Contents' and 'Read & Execute' - When I click the 'Read & Execute' permission checkbox, the checkbox for 'List Folder Contents' also get checked.).

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rafeeque,

Actually I used another command to perform the deploy.

> reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think while running you are using Visual studio self host, not IIS. Can you please go to project properties -> Web tab and configure with IIS and verify? If the problem with IIS please try the ASP.NET configuration is done for your IIS. You don't need to enable any permission for the directory.

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-and-iis6

Hope these helps..

Comment: I tried with any internet browser and it work. However the default internet explorer 6 did not work - maybe I miss out some configuration for IE 6, please advise.

Comment: Also, the link you provided is for ASP 1.1 but I am creating a .NET 3.5 Web Application.